# .htaccess rewrite rule to map a specific query string to a controller

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Trying to crack this following;

```
/any/segment/?zone=116&n-value=a128c471
```

.. to map into a controller `/controller/ads.php`, but to make sure ads.php `REQUEST_URI` and `QUERY_STRING` remains the same (no redirects).

Given from following of course;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !((.*)\.(.*))$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/?%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L,R=301]
```

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: you want "no redirects", then why have you put R=301

Answer (score 0):

1. The URL will fail your third condition. mod_rewrite ignores the query string; it will see a slash at the end of the URL.
2. It's unnecessary to manually add the (verbatim) query string to the end.
3. You need to change the replacement string used by your rewrite rule and remove the `R=301` flag. Depending on what URLs are in use in your site, you might need a more specific regex on the left hand side (or another condition) to exclude the URLs you do not want to rewrite.

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !((.*)\.(.*))$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /controller/ads.php [NC,L]
   ```